# Pulling Data from HTML Tables

Tags: excel, web-scraping, google-sheets

So I understand how to pull data from a single weblink looking at tables. I cannot find not 1 tutorial anywhere on the web about how to do so getting it from Div elements and no one talks about it at all. Can someone please give me an example or something? Either Excel or Google Spreadsheets.

Im trying to teach myself doing so but using this website `https://newworldstatus.com/regions/us-east` for a small project I want to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is both complicated and not all that complicated at the same time.  If you know how it works non-language specifically it all works roughly the same way in VBA.  Do you know how to make a web request in VBA?

Comment: As you are interested in specific html elements I suggest researching xmlhttp requests, as well as looking at the web-scraping questions in the Excel/VBA tags. There are loads of tutorials on the web as well as examples on StackOverflow. Start with  [this](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/vba-macros/videos/vba-scrape-websites/) then https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/. I am not affiliated to either and for the first link, this is just an easy way to access the free YouTube videos in an organised fashion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a comprehensive answer, just intended to show you how some very basic concepts work.  Second, an answer for Sheets, but let me preface all of this by saying that while your test URL seems simple enough, you will not be able to do any of this for that specific URL.  They are either actively trying to stop scraping or they just have it set up in a way that makes it difficult to scrape by accident.  If you directly make a web request to that URL, you will get back the JS code that actually handles the data load-in and not the data itself, so any kind of parsing you try to do will fail because what you see in the page isn't what is actually coming back on the initial page request.  All the html that will be in the page is enough to show this:

[image]

You would need to either try to read through the code and figure out what they're doing, or do some tinkering in the javascript console, and probably some fairly high-level tinkering.  So for a first project, or just to learn some basics, I think I would pick a different test case.

---

First, in VBA. It's both complicated and not all that complicated at the same time.  If you know how web technologies work non-language specifically, then it all works pretty much the same way in VBA.  First, you'll need to make a web request.  You can do that with the winHTTP library or the msXML library.  I usually use winHTTP, but unless what you're doing is complex, either one is fine.

WEB REQUEST:

You'll need to instantiate a request object.  You can do that by either adding a reference to the library (tools->references-> and pick the library out of the list) or you can use late binding.  I prefer to add the reference, because you get intellisense that way.  Here are both:

```
Dim req As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
```

or

```
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```

Then you open the request.  I'm going to assume this is a straight GET.  POST requests get a little more complicated:

```
req.Open "GET", url, TRUE
```

If you have the reference added and created the req with Dim, then you'll get the intellisense and as you type that the arguments will pop up and you can use that to refer to the documentation if you have questions.  TRUE here is to send it asynchronously, which I would do.  If you don't, it will block up the interface.  This the Open method, which you can find in the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/iwinhttprequest-interface

Then use

```
req.send
req.WaitForResponse
source = req.responseText
```

to send the request.  WaitForResponse is needed only if you send the request asynchronously.  The last part is to get the responseText into a variable.

PARSING:

Then you'll need to do some stuff with the MSHTML library, so add a reference to that.  You can also late bind, but I would not, because it will be very helpful to you to have the prompts in intellisense.

First, set up a document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/mshtml.htmldocument?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

and write the source you just fetched to it:

```
Dim doc as new MSHTML.HTMLdocument
doc.write source
```

Now you have a document object you can manipulate.  The trick is to get a reference to the element you want.  There are two methods that will return an element:

```
getElementById
querySelector
```

If you are lucky, the element you are looking for will have a unique ID and you can just get it.  If not so lucky, you can use a selector that identifies it uniquely.  In either case, you will set up an IHTMLElement to return to:

```
Dim el as MSHTML.IHTMLElement
set el = doc.getElementById("uniqueID") 'whatever the unique ID is
```

Once you have that, you can use the methods and properties of the element to return information about it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/mshtml.ihtmlelement?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

There are more specific interfaces, like

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

You can use the generic IHTMLElement, but sometimes there are advantages to using a specific element type, for instance, the properties that are available to it.

Sometimes you will have to set up an IHTMLElementCollection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa703928(v=vs.85)

and iterate it to find the specific element you are looking for.  There are four methods that return collections:

```
getElementsByName
getElementsByTagName
getElementsByClassName
querySelectorAll
```

getElementsByClassName is sometimes problematic, so forewarned is forearmed.

If you need to do that, set up and IHTMLElementCollection and return the list to that:

```
dim els as MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
set els = doc.getElementsByTagName("tagName") 'for instance a for anchors, div for divs
```

That is about it.  There is obviously more to it, but a comprehensive answer would be very long.  This is mostly intended to point you in the right direction and give you more stuff to google.

I will say that you should test out some of these methods in the browser first.  They exist in many languages, and all major browsers have developer tools.  For Chrome, for instance, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the dev tools, and then in the console window type something like:

```
document.getElementById("uniqueID")
```

and you should get the node.  or

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".test") 'where test is the name of the class
document.querySelectorAll("div") ' where you pass a valid CSS selector
```

and you will get the node list.

It will be quicker to experiment there than to try to set it up and debug in VBA.  once you have a good handle on how it works, try to transfer that knowledge to a VBA implementation.

Here is a basic overview of .querySelector to get you started on understanding how those work, although they can get very complicated.  In fact, querySelector is my go to method for finding elements.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

---

Now, Google Sheets:

You don't really want to use IMPORTHTML, even though it seems counterintuitive.  That function (AFAIK) only supports tables and lists, and it's index based, too, which means you give it a number n and it returns the nth table or list in the page.  That means that if they ever change the layout, or the layouts are dynamic in any way, then you won't be able to rely and an index to accurately identify what you want.  Also, as you noted people don't really use tables much anymore, and when they say list I'm pretty sure they mean on  and  elements, which is also not going to be that useful to you.  Here's the docs:

https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&visit_id=637732757707317357-1855795725&rd=2

But you can use IMPORTXML.  Even though it says XML, you can still use it to parse HTML (for reasons and with limitations that are out of scope for this answer).  IMPORTXML takes a URL and an xpath selector.  In this way it's similar to the document.querySelector and querySelectorAll methods. Here is some information on xpath in tutorial from from w3schools.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

And if you want to test selectors in Chrome you can use $x("selector") in the javascript console in the dev tools.  I believe Firefox also supports this, but I am not sure if other browsers do.  If not, you can use document.evaluate:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Even though you can't actually use this in sheets against the URL you've given, let's take a look at a couple of xpath selectors in that context.  Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the dev tools (hopefully you are using Chrome), and then go to the elements tab.  If you don't have the javascript console showing in the bottom pane, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  You should see something like this:

[image]

Use the arrow icon in the top left of the dev tools to search the elements, and just click on the first row in the table:

[image]

so that you can see the structure of the elements, and figure out how to parse out what you want from it.  You'll notice that the cell that's highlighted is contained in a div with a role of "row" and an attribute of row-id.  I think that's where I would start.  So an xpath to that container would look something like this:

```
//div[@row-id=1]
```

where we are fetching all elements (//) that match div and have an attribute (@) of row-id = 1.

If you want to get the children of that container, you just add another level to the path

```
//div[@row-id=1]/div
```

where we want to get all children (/) that are divs.

And I notice that they all have a col-id attribute, so if you wanted to fetch the "set" information you'd just specify divs that have an attribute of col-id = 'set':

```
//div[@row-id=1]/div[@col-id='set']
```

and to get the text out of that:

```
//div[@row-id=1]/div[@col-id='set']/text()[1]
```

since it looks like the second node is the one that has the team name in it.  Again, you can see how this WOULD work in the dev tools, but you won't actually be able to use this for your URL.

I'm not going to spend a lot of time here.  As already stated, you won't be able to use this method on your specific URL.  If you can figure out the actual URL that your URL wraps around, then perhaps.  Also, since there's only one argument, the selector, then there's not much more to expound on.  If you needed something more complex, like the ability to iterate over a set of matching nodes, you could probably do it in Scripts, but I would probably just switch to Excel if it started getting that complicated.  The only exception would be if the data was JSON formatted, in which case Scripts will be able to handle that better than VBA, although I would probably switch to a different language entirely in that case.

Since your URL is probably not good for testing, I'm going to point you to this tutorial from Geckoboard, which has a few different examples from sites like Wikipedia and Pinterest.

https://www.geckoboard.com/blog/use-google-sheets-importxml-function-to-display-data/

---

So google around, experiment, and let me know if you need any help.  And this was all off the top of my head, so let me know if any of this stuff throws errors so I can edit the answer.

Also, be aware that Excel is not always the right tool for dealing with this.  Very often, while the page might have the elements you are looking for, they will be loaded in with JSON and both php and javascript can natively handle JSON objects, while VBA doesn't.  If the data is JSON formatted, it is much easier to parse it out of that than trying to parse it out of the DOM structure (DOM = document object model, another thing to google).  Also, in many cases, if the data is loaded in with AJAX, it won't be returned with your winHTTP call, because that doesn't execute any javascript that might be in the page.

Further, in many cases you will need to set headers or cookies in the winHTTP call to get the data (calls without the right setings might return an error or a redirect).  That is also not addressed in my answer, although you can set headers and cookies in winHTTP.  You would need to sniff the calls, either with Fiddler or similar or with the network tab in dev tools, to find out the right combination of information to pass with your request.

Comment: Ahh... thats alot compared to 

`=IMPORTHTML("https://newworldstatus.com/regions/us-east", "._nWs-askllczh6mn div:nth-of-type(n+5) div[aria-colindex='1']")`

 :( Everything else you just took your time typing here really confused me though. I am sorry but could you please explain it a tad bit more so I could understand?

Comment: It's fine.  That whole answer was "it's more complicated than you think but you need to know the right things to google so here's an overview".  Also, it seems like I missed the google sheets tag on the question.  I thought I was answering an Excel question.  You can do that in google sheets, but it's going to be a little different.  Start by exploring some of the concepts I laid out there.  If you don't know how to use a selector or ID to get an element, it won't matter if it's Excel or Sheets.

Comment: I probably understand alot better if you had a live example like `=IMPORTHTML("https://newworldstatus.com/regions/us-east", "._nWs-askllczh6mn div:nth-of-type(n+5) div[aria-colindex='1']")` for google sheets or even MS Excel because I have both, rather than me breaking out a notepad or vscode to do everything youve said above. But a true live example is probably the easiest for me to learn and querying Tables or Lists in which no one explains what to do if the website does not use TABLES because no one uses tables in web development anymore and all uses Div. Im not trying to be complicated

Comment: @FiVVR That answer is specifically for MS Excel VBA, not notepad or vscode.  I'll check and see how to work that out in sheets for a live example, but be aware that google scripts is highly different from VBA.

Comment: Thank you kindly @Chris Strckland

Comment: I just updated the answer, but you're probably not going to like it.  You can't use either method with your URL because it's not the actual URL to the data.  You would want to use IMPORTXML in google sheets, but you would have to find out the actual URL first.

Comment: Actually, that made more sense to me, thank you :)